# Constructing a bijection between $[a,b)$ to $(0,1)$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

> Construct a bijection between $[a,b)$ to $(0,1)$

I'll be using a technique that builds the function in steps from one interval to the next:

$[a,b)\overset{x-a+1}\to[1,b-a+1)\overset{\frac 1 {x+1}}\to(0,1)$

Now composing the function from the end to the beginning: $f(x)=\frac 1 {1+()}=\frac 1 {1+(x-a+1)}=\frac 1 {x-a+2}$

Now since all the operations were linear we have a bijection, but is it right?

EDIT:

$[a,b)\overset{x-a}\to[0,b-a)\overset{\frac x {b-a}, x\neq0 , 0.5, x=0}\to(0,1)$

$f(x)=\begin{cases}  \frac {(x-a)} {b-a} &x\neq0 \\ 0.5  &x=0\end {cases}$

Comment: The operation $x \mapsto \frac{1}{x+1}$ is not linear.

Comment: There are a couple of problems. The proposed mapping does not take $b$ into account, and the image is nowhere near $(0,1)$. Subtracting $a$ in the first step and dividing by $b-a$ in the second step would send $[a,b)$ to $[0,1)$, close, but we need now to "hide" $a$.

Comment: What do you mean by these empty brackets in $\frac{()}{b-a}$? And just saying “$x$” is not a statement and therefore cannot act as a condition for your cases

Comment: @AndréNicolas will my edit work?

Comment: @Lukas I'm composing the function from the end to the beginning that's why I leave the $()$, about the $x$ it was a typo.

Comment: What is your final answer? You gave two definitions of a function called $f$. I cannot really follow your argumentation there.

Comment: @Lukas the last one.

Comment: This is not a bijection. Both $f(0)$ and $f(\frac{b+a}{2})$ will give you $\frac{1}{2}$!

Comment: @kuhaku:  Apologies, I was away. As I mentioned in a comment, the mapping you used is a bijection from $[a,b)$ to $[0,1)$. We want now to map $[0,1)$ bijectively to $(0,1)$. How to do that is a little tricky, and is well explained in Lukas's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest taking different steps here: First, show $[a,b)\leftrightarrow[0,1)$, and then $[0,1)\leftrightarrow(0,1)$.

The first one is just repositioning and scaling of the interval; you will find the bijection $$f: [a,b)\leftrightarrow[0,1), x\mapsto \frac{x-a}{b-a}$$

Now, we just have to “insert” the element $0$ into the open interval $(0,1)$. The “trick” I will use here is the concept of the [Hilbert Hotel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_paradox_of_the_Grand_Hotel), which basically takes an infinite (bijective) sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ in this interval, mapping every element $a_n$ to $a_{n+1}$ and “inserting” $0$ to $a_0$, which is now “empty” because of the shifting we did.
Therefore, we can define the following bijection:
$$g: [0,1)\leftrightarrow(0,1), x\mapsto\begin{cases}a_0 & x=0\\a_{n+1} & \exists n\in\mathbb N: x=a_n\\x & \text{else}\end{cases}$$
Where $∀ n\inℕ:\left(a_n\in(0,1) \land \not∃ m\inℕ\setminus\{n\}:a_n=a_m \right)$.

By the way, the inverse is
$$g^{-1}: (0,1)\leftrightarrow[0,1), x\mapsto\begin{cases}0 & x=a_0\\a_{n-1} & \exists n\in\mathbb N\setminus\{0\}: x=a_n\\x & \text{else}\end{cases}$$

Comment: How does the final function looks like? i.e. the bijection $[a,b)\to (0,1)$

Comment: You do not need that in order to show that these two intervals are bijective, because for two bijective $f$ and $g$, $g\circ f$ is bijective as well. If you want I will add a proof for that.

Comment: I still don't understand how you can use a sequence on the reals, since they're compact there is no $a_{n+1}$.

Comment: What you you mean by “there is no $a_{n+1}$? Of course there is, because we defined it to be a sequence with a natural index $n\inℕ$, and for every natural number, you have a successor. Do you mean something like “there is no $a_{n+1}$ with a certain property”?
And what should the sequence be in if not the reals?
I do not see how the compactness of $ℝ$ changes something in my argumentation.

Comment: How is the sequence defined? What I mean by no successor is for example: $a_1=0.1, a_2=0.2$ but there's $\aleph_1$ numbers between $a_1,a_2$.

Comment: How many numbers between the elements of the sequence are does not matter, because you leave every $x\in[0,1)$ which _isn't_ represented by that sequence _unmapped_; this is the “else” part of the bijection.
The sequence can be anything that is completely in $(0,1)$ and does not give the same value for different arguments. It could be something like $\frac{1}{n+2}$ which is strictly decreasing and always $>0$.

Comment: Ah I see. The final function would simply be a composition $g\circ f$?

Comment: Exactly. To avoid confusion, let me write it as $g(f(x))$. Applying $f$ leads you to $[0,1)$, and applying $g$ gives you $(0,1)$.